# Why is Keras fit_generator different from fit?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, image-preprocessing

I would like to use a custom generator so that I can implement custom augmentations on my dataset in Keras. However, I built a generic generator (without augmentation) and am confused why it is performing way worse than the built-in fit function.

My generator looks like this:

```
def data_generator_plain(features, labels, batch_size):

    batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, NUM_CHANNELS), dtype=np.float64)
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, NUM_KEYPOINTS * 2), dtype=np.float64)

    while True:
        steps = len(batch_features) // batch_size
        for i in range(steps):
            for j in range(batch_size):
                batch_features[j] = features[(i*batch_size)+j]
                batch_labels[j] = labels[(i*batch_size)+j]

            yield batch_features, batch_labels
```

and when i call `model.fit_generator(data_generator_plain(X_train, y_train, BATCH_SIZE), steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))` the val_accuracy ends around 73% while the basic `model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))` val_accuracy ends around 93%.

Is my generator implementation correct? In theory, it should perform the same as the built-in fit function, right? I imagine it is not showing the algorithm all the examples it needs to. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot spot a big problem. Maybe because [fit](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) has argument `shuffle=True` by default. If X_train.shape[0] is not a multiple of BATCH_SIZE, it would be another small discrepancy. Or maybe there is a bug in some other part of your code. You can always insert some print statements and manually debug such problems.

Answer (score 1):

The **Keras** fit_generator takes in a python generator as an input to train the model over an array of training data. Usually, these generators are formed using built-in Keras functions such as *ImageDataGenerator* that takes in the image array as inputs and performs user-defined operations (such as augmentations, normalization, transformations, etc.) on the same in real time. This considerably reduces the memory consumption.

For more, refer [Keras image preprocessing docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: The .fit function also accepts generators